# Comparison for multiple rows in a subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a problem that requires me to write a complex comparison for a query.
I have a table that loks like this:

**GD_TD_REG**

```
DEP_ID                               DEP_REG_ID VAL_R   ACT_DT
9A52C076-D2B0-4732-BA63-FFF587BEEC9D    DP001   1559    2018-09-01T00:00:00Z
9A52C076-D2B0-4732-BA63-FFF587BEEC9D    DP005   306009  2018-09-01T00:00:00Z
34F30775-220C-4E62-8673-FFF9E8BE02AB    DP005   0       2018-09-01T00:00:00Z
33CDABA4-F0E3-4209-9DFE-FFFF5BE24A7F    DP005   97      2018-09-01T00:00:00Z
9A52C076-D2B0-4732-BA63-FFF587BEEC9D    DP001   1559    2018-08-30T00:00:00Z
33CDABA4-F0E3-4209-9DFE-FFFF5BE24A7F    DP005   997     2018-08-28T00:00:00Z
...
```

There is a `DEP_REG_ID` field that specifies the transactions and can take the following values: `DP001`, `DP005`, and `DP004`. `VAL_R` is the value for which operation was performed. The `ACT_DT` is a date when the row was entered and the `DEP_ID` is ID of a user.

The query is as follows:

1. I am given a date of interest. For example `'2018-08-28 00:00:00'`.
2. For this date, I need to find LAST 'DP005' operation for every user. Meaning the last `ACT_DT`.
3. Then, I need to take the values from `VAL_R` for these dates.
4. To these values add all the `'DP001'` starting from the date of last `'DP005'` and to the date of interest. Also, the sum is unique for every user.
5. Subtract all the `'DP004'` from the date of `'DP005'` to the interest date.
6. Return value for every user of these operations.

I use MySQL for this.

I've tried to write separate queries to extract data.

```
SELECT @Date_interest := '2018-08-28 00:00:00';
SELECT @Previous_date := DATE_SUB(@Date_interest, INTERVAL 30 DAY);

SELECT @Max_date := MAX(ACT_DT) FROM GD_TD_REG
WHERE ACT_DT <= @Date_interest GROUP BY DEP_ID;

SELECT @Last_change := VAL_R FROM GD_TD_REG 
                             WHERE DEP_REG_ID = 'DP005' AND 
                              ACT_DT <= @Max_date
                              GROUP BY DEP_ID;

SELECT @Last_change_date := ACT_DT FROM GD_TD_REG 
                             WHERE DEP_REG_ID = 'DP005' AND 
                              ACT_DT <= @Max_date
                              GROUP BY DEP_ID;

SELECT @Positive_transactions := SUM(IF(DEP_REG_ID = 'DP001',VAL_R,0))
FROM GD_TD_REG 
WHERE DEP_REG_ID = 'DP001' AND 
ACT_DT BETWEEN @Previous_date AND @Date_interest 
GROUP BY DEP_ID;

SELECT @Negative_transactions := SUM(IF(DEP_REG_ID = 'DP004',VAL_R,0))
FROM GD_TD_REG 
WHERE ACT_DT BETWEEN @Previous_date AND @Date_interest 
GROUP BY DEP_ID;
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6a3f3/91) for example of data.

But I have a problem with putting the queries together. The variables can not store multiple values. So I've tried to put the variables into subqueries of one main query. But, when I need to find dates that are less or equal to the list of last `'DP005'` operations it gives me an error: `subquery returns more than 1 row`.

I need to get something like:

**GD_TD_REG**

```
DEP_ID                                  SUM     
9A52C076-D2B0-4732-BA63-FFF587BEEC9D    307568
34F30775-220C-4E62-8673-FFF9E8BE02AB    0
33CDABA4-F0E3-4209-9DFE-FFFF5BE24A7F    97
...
```

Where for each user value got from Last `VAL_R` of `DP005` + `sum(VAL_R)` of all `DP001` - `sum(VAL_R)` of all `DP004`.

For example for user: `9A52C076-D2B0-4732-BA63-FFF587BEEC9D` the last value DP005 was on `ACT_DT` = `2018-09-01T00:00:00Z`, `VAL_R = 306009`. Add 1559 the sum of all entries of type `DP001` and subtract 0 the sum of all types of `DP004` since date `DP005`. So the entry, in the end, is `306009 + 1559 = 307568`.

I added a previous date variable, which I am using for queries. However, I have to change it onto `@Last_change_date`.

So I've stuck on this one. What do I missing?

Comment: Please add your expected outcome as text to the question based on your sample data.

Comment: I am unclear what you want - you seem to want a simple aggregation by dep_id for a specified date so I don't get 'starting from the date of last 'DP005'

Comment: Ah yes, sure. I Forgot about adding an example of a successful task, thanks.

Comment: Also, the entry that provides 'DP005' appears on some date and overwrites all previous entries. So We need to use this value and perform other operations starting from the date of this operation.